# Ruby on Rails performance on ARM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, arm

I was wondering if we could replace our Atom N270 based nettops that are running a Rails (ruby 1.8.6...) webapp with some equivalent ARM based device (we like the fanless setup, power consumption, etc.).

The ARM device was XScale-PXA270 @ 520, 128MB (and probably some slower SDRAMs), running linux, there was always enough free memory  with comparable performance as a jailbroken iPhone.

Benchmarking the production database (SQLite) gave us promising results (ARM was just 
20-30% slower), so I tried to build ruby (1.9.2p0).

The rails app was running very slowly on ARM (fetching from sql and generating templates 10-20x slower). I've decided run some benchmarks to find bottlenecks.

Again, some results were ok (on par with older ruby 1.8.6 we are using now, 6x slower than ruby 1.9.2), and some were very slow (20-30x slower). Fe. it looks that hash methods are 40x slower on ARM. Running [Ruby Benchmark Suite](http://github.com/acangiano/ruby-benchmark-suite) showed more bottlenecks, strings, threads, arrays...

I knew ARM is slower than Atom, I was just not expecting such a huge difference, especially after SQLite was running fine.

Is there some flaw with Ruby on ARM, do I need to apply some patches, is this hopeless and should rewrite the whole app in C if I want to use the ARM  device or just the device has not enough computing power?

**Examples**

```
def fib(n) 
  return 1 if n < 2
  fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
end 

Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report { fib(32) }
  x.report { fib(36) }
  x.report { h = {}; (0..10**3).each {|i| h[i] = i}  } 
  x.report { h = {}; (0..10**4).each {|i| h[i] = i}  } 
  x.report { h = {}; (0..10**5).each {|i| h[i] = i}  } 
end
```

```
ruby -rbenchmark bench.rb
```

Atom N270, 1GB

```
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i686-linux]
      user     system      total        real
  2.440000   0.000000   2.440000 (  2.459400)
 16.780000   0.030000  16.810000 ( 17.293015)
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001180)
  0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.012180)
  0.160000   0.000000   0.160000 (  0.161803)

ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i686-linux]
      user     system      total        real
 12.500000   0.020000  12.520000 ( 12.628106)
 84.450000   0.170000  84.620000 ( 85.879380)
  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.002216)
  0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.032939)
  0.240000   0.010000   0.250000 (  0.255756)
```

XScale-PXA270 @ 520, 128MB 
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [arm-linux]

```
      user     system      total        real
 12.470000   0.000000  12.470000 ( 12.526507)
 85.480000   0.000000  85.480000 ( 85.939294)
  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.060643)
  0.640000   0.000000   0.640000 (  0.642136)
  6.460000   0.130000   6.590000 (  6.605553)
```

Build with:

```
 ./configure --host=arm-linux --without-X11 --disable-largefile \
--enable-socket=yes --without-Win32API --disable-ipv6 \
--disable-install-doc --prefix=/opt --with-openssl-include=/opt/include/ \
--with-openssl-lib=/opt/include/lib

ENV:

PFX=arm-iwmmxt-linux-gnueabi

export DISCIMAGE="/opt"
export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-linux-"
export HOST="arm-linux"
export TARGET="arm-linux"
export CROSS_COMPILING=1
export CC=$PFX-gcc
export CFLAGS="-O3 -I/opt/include"
export LDFLAGS="-O3 -L/opt/lib/"
#LIBS=
#CPPFLAGS=
export CXX=$PFX-g++
#CXXFLAGS=
export CPP=$PFX-cpp

export OBJCOPY="$PFX-objcopy"
export LD="$PFX-ld"
export AR="$PFX-ar" 
export RANLIB="$PFX-ranlib"
export NM="$PFX-nm"
export STRIP="$PFX-strip"
export ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void=yes
export ac_cv_func_isinf=no
export ac_cv_func_isnan=no
export ac_cv_func_finite=no
```

Comment: Why are you running nettops as production servers? You should have a real server and the nettops **connecting** to that to browse the webapps, you shouldn't be running the web app locally on nettops **EDIT** if you're talking about development machines refer to [the programmer's bill of rights](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/the-programmers-bill-of-rights.html)

Comment: I notice "ruby" tagged questions typically have only 10-20 views, so the ruby community here on SO is small.  As in my "answer", I suggest going to a mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're complaining that optimizations new in Ruby 1.9.2 (when compared to 1.8.x) are x86 specific.  The Atom and ARM performance is comparable for Ruby 1.8.x.  Perhaps you could ask a ruby-specific mailing list.  A quick search shows that yes, there were many changes in Ruby 1.9.x:

> Ruby 1.9.2 brings [...] major speed improvements to Ruby by way of the Yet Another Ruby VM (YARV) interpreter

Perhaps the right question is "Does YARV have x86 specific optimizations? Could these optimizations be duplicated in the ARM port?"

Answer (score 2):

The same benchmark on raspberry pi with a bit newer packages:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [armv6l-linux-eabihf]
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ruby benchmark.rb 
       user     system      total        real
   6.580000   0.000000   6.580000 (  6.585575)
  45.080000   0.000000  45.080000 ( 45.132900)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.008709)
   0.090000   0.000000   0.090000 (  0.095851)
   1.040000   0.010000   1.050000 (  1.044347)
```

Update for a RP2 (in 2015):

```
pi@raschpi ~ $ uname -a
Linux raschpi 4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raschpi ~ $ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [armv7l-linux-eabihf]
pi@raschpi ~ $ ruby benchmark.rb 
       user     system      total        real
   4.450000   0.000000   4.450000 (  4.446841)
  30.460000   0.000000  30.460000 ( 30.473665)
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.002306)
   0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.023236)
   0.290000   0.000000   0.290000 (  0.292746)
```

Update for a RP3-B (in 2017 - Raspian Jessie):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [arm-linux-gnueabihf]
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ruby -rbenchmark benchmark.rb
       user     system      total        real
   4.030000   0.000000   4.030000 (  4.032046)
  30.940000   0.000000  30.940000 ( 30.943480)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001352)
   0.000000   0.010000   0.010000 (  0.013266)
   0.260000   0.000000   0.260000 (  0.251937)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the code quoted in the question's example, these are my results on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian with an armv6l processor:

```
uname -a
Linux ginger 3.1.9+ #168 PREEMPT Sat Jul 14 18:56:31 BST 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux

ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [armv6l-linux-eabi]

ruby benchmark.rb
   user     system      total        real
 7.810000   0.000000   7.810000 (  7.823737)
53.520000   0.010000  53.530000 ( 53.630399)
 0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.007818)
 0.090000   0.000000   0.090000 (  0.090667)
 0.950000   0.030000   0.980000 (  0.980731)
```